# Concerning a ghast's Stench (after death), Stench (3.5 vs Pathfinder), and Paralysis

Tags: pathfinder-1e

A [Ghast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul/ghoul-ghast/) has:

> **Stench (Ex):** Ghast’s exude an overwhelming stink of death and corruption in a 10-foot radius.  Those within the stench must succeed at a DC 15 Fortitude save, or be sickened for 1d6+4 minutes.

If a player kills the ghast, and the corpse of the ghast is still lying on the ground, and a player that hasn't been within 10 feet of the ghast starts pilfering through its pockets... would that player then be affected by stench, despite the ghast being dead?

---

In D&D 3.5, creatures immune to poison were immune to stench<sup>1</sup>. I don't see that in Pathfinder. That means stench has nothing to do with poison? The [Neutralize Poison](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/neutralize-poison/) spell would have no effect on the [sickened](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Sickened) condition from stench?

---

A ghast can paralyze an elf<sup>2</sup>. Duergar are also immune to paralysis. Could a ghast paralyze a duergar, or is that explicitly an elf-thing?

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>A delay poison or neutralize poison spell removes the effect from a sickened creature. Creatures with immunity to poison are unaffected, and creatures resistant to poison receive their normal bonus on their saving throws.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Unlike ghouls, A ghast’s paralysis even affects elves.</sub>

Comment: As far as I can see you've got three different questions here. Wouldn't it be better to ask each one separately?

Comment: @harlandski Meh. They're short questions and all about ghasts. I did, however, find the title a bit misleading.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I changed the title to incorporate all.

Comment: One question per post, please. (For one reason, properly tagging every subject here requires more tags than are allowed on a post. Also, s'the rules and this isn't new.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### On the stench of destroyed [ghasts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul/ghoul-ghast/)

Absent text to the contrary, this GM assumes effects like a [ghast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul/ghoul-ghast/)'s stench continue indefinitely, and a destroyed ghast nonetheless remains a ghast. So, for this GM, in the same way that a dead [red dragon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/chromatic-red/) remains immune to fire, a dead ghast remains stinky, and the previously unaffected rogue that decides to go through the destroyed ghast's pockets risks suffering the effects of the ghast's stench. Another GM's opinion may differ as this perspective requires considering some long-term campaign implications (e.g. building fortresses from destroyed [stone golems](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-stone/) so the fortress gains the golem's immunity to magic).

#### On the ghast's stench as a poison

It looks like the ghast's stench is no longer a semi-poison as it was in [*D&D 3.5e*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monstersG.html#ghoul). Interestingly, the third-party sounds-sort-of-like-ghoul [ghul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/ghul-cr-2/) has the supernatural ability exhalation of death, which *is* affected by spells countering poison.

#### On paralyzing elves

A ghast's supernatural ability paralysis says, "Unlike ghouls, A ghast’s paralysis even affects elves," but that doesn't mean it'll affect *other* creatures broadly immune to paralysis like a [duergar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/duergar/).

Comment: Agreed.  Bodies have a tendency to get *more stinky* after they're dead, not less. Although as undead, I suppose this is at least part of why they're so stinky to begin with. =P

Comment: @Steve-O Yeah, the only real issue that arises is to what extent a destroyed undead creature is *actually* destroyed, which is something the game leaves to the GM.

Comment: I'm running a duergar campaign, and borrowing from the Zolurket Mines (Dungeons of Golarion). I am preparing as much as I can in advance and don't want to be caught with my pants down.